# Sliding down slopes

Tags: game-engine

In the game engine, when i have my player walking around the scene it seems to slowly slide down slopes and ramps etc. How can I prevent this sliding from happening just like in most other games?

Comment: Turn up friction on character's physics?

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I've experienced this also without being able to fix it +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

connect all the sensors you are using for motion to a python controller.

add a ray sensor, -z that will reach from the origin to below the actors lower collision bound. connect this as well,

```
sensors --------python
Ray-------------/
```

break

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

own = cont.owner
Ray = cont.sensors['Ray']

your_sensor_1 = cont.sensors['YourSensor']


## etc

if not your_sensor.positive and Ray.positive:
    own.worldLinearVelocity*=.9
    own.applyForce((0,0,(own.mass*9.8)),0)
##if you are on the ground and not pressing any movement keys like forward or backward 
## stop moving
```

Comment: You forget to set the ray sensor to true pulse triggering, but thanks anyway. It worked after that.