# How do I prevent a physics character object from sliding down inclines when they are no longer in motion by the player?

Tags: game-engine

I have a 3rd person character that continues to slide down hills if I stop providing move input. The blender file bellow is a stripped down example. Essentially I am trying to stop on the hill without sliding down.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bt1iv5e1gx616qt/FIXPLAYERSLIDING.blend?dl=0

I tired the solution suggested here but it does not work.

Comment: what i already tried
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24034/sliding-down-slopes